# What is this adhesive tape that comes in some parts?

Tags: pcb, surface-mount, pcb-fabrication

I think this is a Mylar tape, but why they come with it? I guess its so to make the Pick and Place machine job easier? 
And why is so common to find them holding cables inside some laptops? Just because they are fire resistant?

[image: USB SMD with tape]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Its kapton tape. It has two very interesting properties - its a great insulator, and its heat resistant - to the point where flexible circuit boards are made from it. You can solder without melting it (or even solder it), which makes it great for protecting parts from shorting when wave soldering.

Comment: As far as I know, kapton tape is fragile and will wear with time, so I don't know how those flexible circuits stand with time and lots of movement...

Answer (score 6):

I was told once that the tape is there to provide a flat surface for a sucker on a pick and place machine.

Answer (score 5):

[Kapton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapton) is the tradename for polyimide tape

Comment: Thanks for the name...but do you have an answer?

Comment: I guess I expected you to read the reference link. when a thin tape works from -273 to +400 °C used as a substrate for FPCA and the outside layer of space suits, IR & wave soldering. What more would you like to know?  My answer was a rhetorical Yes.

Comment: It comes from polymerized aromatics {dianhydride & diamine} goes into speaker voice coils, space suits, as thin as 0.3mil, rated > 5kV/mil @200'C, >10kV/mil @-500'F is similar to most good plastic. Can be Corona resistant, tinted, "some" types are; moisture resistant, more tensile stable, anti-stat, cryogenic resistant, limited outgassing, but not suitable for human implants

Comment: hahahaha thanks for the complete description of the Kapton...I did read it, but I just didnt find a straight answer...now I know it is used because it can stand the heat of the electronics, and can protect some pieces from the wave solder and provide a good surface for the pick and place machine.

Comment: I guess the unscientific answer is cause it is the only plastic tape that wont melt in the oven.